# Cycling Backwards through Tabs in Tab Control with Button Click

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, buttonclick

Below is the code I'm using to cycle through the tabs going one direction:

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            projInfo.SelectedIndex = (projInfo.SelectedIndex + 1) % projInfo.TabCount;
        }
```

**Question:**

How can I change this code to have it cycle backwards (or right to left) instead of left to right?  I tried changing the `+1` to `-1` but to no luck.

Comment: What failed with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `+1` to `-1` is a right direction. You just have to handle one special case when the current selected index is `0` and the next one have to be `tabCount-1`.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newIndex = projInfo.SelectedIndex - 1;
    if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = projInfo.TabCount - 1;
    projInfo.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
}
```